# Select in rawQuery method in Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

How to compare text fields? My column name is `Semester` and there is an entry `"V"` in it.

```
Cursor result =
    db.rawQuery("Select * from bookTable where Semester like 'V';",null);
if(result.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        if(name==null) {
           name= result.getString(3);
        } else {
            name+= result.getString(3);
    } while(result.moveToNext());
} else {
    name="no value";
}   
return name;
```

it returns `"no value"` in name string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your sql query:

```
Cursor result =
db.rawQuery("Select * from bookTable where Semester = 'V'",null);
```

Comment: hey thanx.... i had used this query also.. but i had put a semicolon at the end of it.. it works

Comment: @VIPULGOYAL I agree with Nishant - you are new to stackoverflow, but you should learn that in order for all of us get the most benefit from the site the question askers should also take care. If he solved your issue you should accept his answer via clicking the empty check on the left of the answer. Also consider upvoting him. Upvote means that you like the contents of his answer and find them useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for a column with a given name why you use like in first place? Use ordinary query clause:

```
String tableName = "bookTable";
String whereClause = "Semester = ?";
String [] whereArgs = { "V" };
Cursor result =
    db.query(tableName, null, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, null);
```